# Facebook sentiment analysis

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, nlp, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis

```
import json   
import facebook
```

when i import facebook then got error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-2-ee110440bf43>", line 1, in <module>
    import facebook

  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\facebook.py", line 222
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

please need help!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the right Python version to import the library in your notebook. Since Python 3.x the `except Something as` is required, and the comma version `except urllib2.HTTPError, e:` - that is triggering the error - is not.

In order to do this check you should try to write in your notebook something like this:

```py
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Comment: hi thanks, i got this 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]. is it mean that i can not import on python 3?

Comment: Can you please link the library are you trying to import?